# Can't save map with different projection in QGIS

Tags: openlayers-2, kml, qgis, epsg

I'm using QGIS 2.4 and am opening a shapefile I downloaded (specifically from: http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/110m/physical/ne_110m_coastline.zip).

What I would like to do is convert the shapefile to EPSG:3857 and then save it as a KML (or some other format easily readable by OpenLayers).  I attempt to do this within QGIS by opening the shapefile (EPSG:4326), right clicking on the layer->Save As then I choose KML, set my CRS to EPSG:3857 and then I save.

Unfortunately, after opening the new file in QGIS it always tells me the layer is still EPSG:4326.  I am opening from a clean project in QGIS (so as to be sure its not inheriting the projects projection).  All the things I have read online tell me to convert projections in this way.  Additionally, I am getting no weird output in the terminal from which I have opened QGIS.

Am I missing something here or doing something wrong?

Comment: Ah, good idea.  Thanks for the help.  I guess I cant directly move the question, so I will have to ask it again there...

Comment: Are you trying to save a map or a layer in a different projection?  ou can re-project a layer to display it differently than its native projection by setting the project CRS to the one you like. Saving the layer in a different projection should be Look into the global CRS settings. It is usually set to start all projects as WGS84 and to re-project the layers to that CRS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the GDAL manual http://www.gdal.org/drv_kml.html:

> Note that KML by specification uses only a single projection,
>   EPSG:4326. All OGR KML output will be presented in EPSG:4326. As such
>   OGR will create layers in the correct coordinate system and transform
>   any geometries.

So there is nothing much you can do about it, except looking for another file format.